# Disable Touch for the whole Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How Can I disable or Block Touch in Android Studio for a whole Activity?
I know how to disable touch for a Single or more Views but not how to disable it for a whole activity...

Answer (score 7):

Use this it's really simple:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

And to get touch back:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

block touch event

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```